# VB6 code to PHP conversion

Tags: php, vb6

I am currently working on a project to convert VB6 code to PHP and I need some help. I would like to know if my conversion of my checksum function is correct because the value that I am getting is not accurate at all.

VB6 Code:

```
Function CheckSum(St As String) As Long
 Dim A As Long, B As Long
 For A = 1 To Len(St)
     B = B + Asc(Mid$(St, A, 1))
 Next A
 CheckSum = B
End Function
```

TO

PHP Code:

```
Function CheckSum($st)
{

For($a=0; $a<Count($st); $a++)
{
$B = $B + SubStr($st,$a,1);
}
return $B;
}
```

The whole PHP code:

```
Function CheckSum($st)
{

For($a=0; $a<Count($st); $a++)
{
$B = $B + SubStr($st,$a,1);
}
return $B;
}

Function DoubleChar($num)
{
$DoubleChar = Chr(IntVal($num / 256)) + Chr($num % 256);
Return $DoubleChar;
}

$host = '127.0.0.1'; 
$port = 7973; 
$waitTimeoutInSeconds = 1; 
if($fp = fsockopen($host,$port,$errCode,$errStr,$waitTimeoutInSeconds))
{   
$getplayers = DoubleChar(Chr(35)) + Chr(CheckSum(Chr(35)) * 20 % 194) + Chr(0) + Chr(35);
if(fwrite($fp, $getplayers)):
while (!feof($fp)) 
{
    $buffer = fread($fp, 256);
echo IntVal($buffer);
}   
endif;
} else {
echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
} 
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Use lowercase: "function ..." instead of "Function ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VisualBasic `checksum` code you posted operates over each character of the string st and transforms it to its Ansi code equivalent (the `Asc()` function). Moreover the VB code uses the `Len()` function to operate on the string whereas your PHP code is using the `count()` function, which operates over an array.

In order to achieve the equivalent result in PHP you'll need to use a similar function such as [ord()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php) with [strlen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) so your checksum function would look something like:

```
function CheckSum($st)
{
    for($a=0; $a<strlen($st); $a++)
    {
        $B = $B + ord(substr($st,$a, 1));
    }
    return $B;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to know if my conversion of checksum is correct because the value that I am getting is not accurate at all.

If the results don't match - then conversion is not correct.

Comment: @user765071: so what? You've asked if conversion is correct - I replied that: Not, it's not correct.

Comment: @user765071: I will also bold my answer: **NO, IT'S NOT CORRECT, BECAUSE RESULTS DON'T MATCH**